# SQLCipher CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed

Tags: android, eclipse, string, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm integrating SQLCipher in a application with a SQLite Db. when the app is launch, I receive a "application has stopped unexpectedly" error. When I look at LogCat I see the initial error is "CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed". The only change I have made to this application is adding the code to integrate SQLCIpher. I'm sure I have not coded it properly but am not sure what i missed. the following has been done:

1.java.io.file, info,guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase, android.os.Bundle, and android.app.activity have been imported.
2. InitializeSQLCipher() has been added to the onCreate method of the splash activity

```
private void InitializeSQLCipher() {
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
    File databaseFile = getDatabasePath ("mydatabase.db");
    databaseFile.mkdirs();
    databaseFile.delete();
    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "password", null);
    database.execSQL("create table t1(a, b)");
    database.execSQL("insert into t1(a, b) values(?, ?)", new Object[]{"one for the money", "two for the show"});
     }
```

Comment: FWIW, here is a sample app showing SQLCipher in use: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the "." from databasename.db (e.g.databasedb)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that you have not moved the ICU resource files into the assets directory. Make sure you copy the icu*.zip into your assets folder and include it in your build.

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare has provided sample code illustrating the concept. Check it out [**here**](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure).